# Saving a txt file into a folder in the same folder as the cpp file in C++

Tags: c++

I want to make a program that can save a text file into a folder that is in the same folder as the `cpp` file without having to write down the full path, as the location of the `cpp` file may be changed.

Example:

I have my `cpp` in a file called `CppFileLocation` on my desktop: `C:\Users\user\Desktop\CppFileLocation\file.cpp`

I want it to save the text file into a folder called `CppFileHistory`:
`C:\Users\user\Desktop\CppFileLocation\CppFileHistory\textfile.txt`

It should work without writing the full path: `C:\Users\user\Desktop\CppFileLocation` in the `cpp` file.

I have tried this:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int main()
{
    string filename = "textfile.txt";

    ofstream saveloc;
    saveloc.open("\\CppFileHistory\\" + fileName);
    saveloc << "this is some text.\n";
    saveloc.close();
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: My rhetorical question to you is "what should happen if you run the compiled executable on a different computer?", because there is not really any relationship between the compiled program and the files containing the code. You could always search the user's computer to find the file you want, but a better question is why do you want the program to know where the code files that made it are?

Comment: I am trying to make a cash register program for a project in my college, and part of it is to save the receipts and this is how I want to do it, in a txt file that is in a folder as to not clutter the cpp  file's location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 saveloc.open(".\\CppFileHistory\\" + fileName);
```

with the dot `.`

But I can't guarantee to work. Because a C++ program is supposed to be compiled into an executable, then run the executable. When the executable is run, you basically free to pick its "current working directory". What the above code does is, from the current working directory `.`, find a subdirectory `CppFileHistory`, and in it, open the `fileName`.

What you posted in the question seems to me that you will run the executable under `CppFileLocation`. Hence I suggest the above change.